# search data with angular and php

Tags: php, angularjs

I try when click it button search , router to page search and search data in php . Here is my code

html:

```
<input type="text"  placeholder="Search" ng-model="vm.search">
<button ui-sref="search?({item : vm.search})" class="btn btn-default"></button>
```

router

```
.state('search?',{
    url:'/search?/{item}',
templateUrl:'/saha/src/client/app/search/search.html',
controller:'searchController',
controllerAs:'vm',
resolve:{
searchItems : ['dataServices','$stateParams',function(dataServices,$stateParams) {
                return dataServices.searchItem($stateParams.item)
                                }]
                            }

                        })
```

controller

```
function searchController(logger,$stateParams,searchItems) {
                var vm = this;
                vm.data = searchItems;
                console.log(vm.data);

        }
```

services

```
 function searchItem(item) {
                        return $http({
                            method:'GET',
                            url: 'searchItem.php?item=' + item,
                            data : {
                                item: item
                            },
                            headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                        }).then(function(data) {
                            return data.data;


})
                }
```

And php

```
$row= array();
$item = isset($_GET['item']) ? trim($_GET['item']):'';
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE tensp LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')";
if($stmt= $conn->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$item);
    $stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($r = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
    $row[] =$r;

}
}
echo json_encode($row);
```

But i get empty array in controller . Where is my wrong? Please help me
Here is in console i get
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're getting any data from your API? 
try adding a console.log(data) in your service to verify that it isnt your sql returning an empty array.

Comment: @jonas yes , it getting data . I add img in question . First is console.log in services , and second is console.log in controller